# writing iteration in MIPS

Tags: mips

I am writing this program in MIPS to calculate 2 to a power given by me and sum the sequential powers down to 0. For example, if I put 4 in $a0 like in the code below, I want it to calculate (4^2)+(3^2)+(2^2)+(1^2) which should come out to be 15. It should stop before it reaches zero. This is what I have written so far

```
main: 
addi $a0, $zero, 4    #put k in $a0 in this case 
addi $a1, $zero, 0    #put 0 in current sum
addi $v1, $v1, 0      #tally the total in $v1   
for:  
lw $10, $a0           #load k into reg $10
lw $11, $a1           #load sum into $11
    addi $10, $10, -1     #subtracts 1 from k
    li $9, 0              #sets i in for loop ($9) to 0
```

done:

```
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

I'm new to MIPS and could use a lot of help on finishing this, I know I want to use a for loop, but I don't know how to go through it while subtracting 1 from k and also calculating the sum. How would I bring 2 to a power of k, because I guess there is no power operation in mips. At this point in the course I can only use add, sub, and, or, slt, addi, j, beq, lw, sw, and sll. Can you not use a constant when using sub? Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2):

A power is a multiplication, and a multiplication is a sum. So you can write a function that does a multiplication by adding, and another function that does power by multiplicating. For example, the multiplication function:

```
multiply: # $a0 first factor, $a1 second factor, $v0 result of multiplication
    or $t0, $zr, $zr 
    or $t1, $a1, $a1
    or $t3, $zr, $zr
loop:
    beq $t1, $zr, end
    add $t0, $t0, $a0
    addi $t1, $t1, -1
    j loop
    nop
end:
    or $v0, $t0, $0
    jr $ra
    nop
```

(Please note I haven't tested this, and this will not work with negative numbers)

As a side note, you have MUL instruction as well, but I don't know if you saw that already.

Answer (score 1):

I think the concept your instructor is trying to show you is that `sll`, in effect, multiplies by 2. You've got to think in binary. For example, let's start with 1:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

Do a 'sll' on that, and what do you end up with? `0010` = 2. sll again and you get `0100` = 4. And so on, until you shift all the way over and have `0x80000000`.

So the answer to the question, "How would I bring 2 to a power of k?", is simpler than you might have thought: *you shift 1 by k*.

```
# $t0 contains 'k', the amount we want to shift by
addi $t1, $zero, 1
sllv $t3, $t1, $t0
```

Note: I had to double-check that you can shift by a variable amount, but [this link](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/bitshift.html) says `sllv` is valid. However, since it's not in your list of allowed functions, you'll have to do `sll $t1, $t1, 1` in a loop. (Be sure to put your check at the start of the loop, in case the amount you want to shift by is zero!)

Comment: Power of 2 is not the same as multiplicating by 2 ;)

Comment: @m0skit0 orly? 2*2*2 <> 2^3?

Comment: Dude, read the question: *"I want it to calculate (4^2)+(3^2)+(2^2)+(1^2)"* Now calculate 3^2 using shifting, please.

Comment: Hey, I'm just the messenger. _"I want it to calculate (4^2)+(3^2)+(2^2)+(1^2) which should come out to be 15"_ - um, that would be more like 16+9+4+1, which does **not** come out to 15. And he did ask, "How would I bring 2 to a power of k?". So I concluded that he actually meant 2^4+2^3+2^2+2^1.

Comment: 2^4+2^3+2^2+2^1 is also not 15... This discussion is going nowhere.

Comment: I blame a faulty requirement specification. ;)

Comment: This is my fault I put the calculation in wrong I should have it as (2^4)+(2^3)+(2^2)+(2^1) = 30

Comment: @JosephPlymouth So, did either of our answers help?

Answer (score 0):

**Quick question:**

Are you doing `2^4+2^3.`. etc? or `4^2+3^2` etc? 
Just a quick note:

```
2^4+2^3+2^2+2^1+2^0 = 15.

4^2+3^2+2^2+2^1 != 15.
```

(If it is the first, you do need 2^0 because you need to contemplate for odd numbers, 2^0 = 1. This is how we get odd numbers in binary.)

In this case, the answer about left shift (`lls`) is correct. When you left shift a binary number you increase the exponent of base 2 by 1.

so:

```
0001 = 1
0010 = 2
0100 = 4
1000 = 8
```

These summed give you 15.

So you could shift left, and add the result of each shift to a register.